# What is the purpose/function of this power inductor in parallel?

Tags: power-supply, inductor

The inductor in question is part L3, a power inductor with both coils in parallel. [Datasheet](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/54/RF1260-1391477.pdf).

The complete circuit is the power supply for an RFID reader, where +5V_A is the output for the antenna drivers and +5V for more general purpose stuff.

The question: Why use a "power" inductor in parallel instead of just a "normal" inductor with 22uH @ 100kHz as the datasheet says for this one in parallel configuration?

[image]

Comment: Could be a part used in other things the company makes, rather than adding a new line to the BOM

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a "power" inductor because it needs to carry a significant amount of DC current. Connecting the windings in parallel gives you the same inductance as either winding alone, but with twice the current capacity and half the DC resistance. It's exactly equivalent to a simple coil with the same number of turns, but twice the cross-sectional area of the wire.

Comment: Would it really need to carry significant current? If it's just an RFID reader? This is definitely not my area so am genuinely curious. I thought most would be below 100-200mA?

Comment: 100-200 mA IS significant current for an inductor. Most "small signal" inductors of that value will have saturation currents much lower than that.

Comment: Oh... there seems to be a difference in the question and the schematic. OP states 220uH, but the schematic is written as 220m, which I took for mH. But still, I forgot the saturation current so didn't consider that. +1 from me!

Comment: You only get twice the current capability if the core doesn’t saturate and dramatically reduce its inductance.

Comment: Doesn't two inductors in parallel give half the inductance, not same inductance? AFAIK paralleling inductors works similarly to paralleling resistors.

Comment: @jpa: What you say is true ONLY if the two inductors do NOT share any magnetic field. When you have two windings on the same core, it's a completely different story.

Comment: @DaveTweed Ah, good point.

Answer (score 10):

Unless the designer is here, there is no way to really know for certain. Perhaps it was a cheaper option. Maybe it had the best performance under tests conditions compared with other inductors?

If the company that designed this already use that component in another design, it makes sense to re-use it on another product. It saves having to buy a new component, and could reduce the price of the current one if they then have to purchase a higher quantity.

In some products I have designed I have used inductors for many different reasons. Some of them the reason I mentioned above. We already stocked that part and it happened to be the same value as I needed, so I used that.

Sometimes I just follow the datasheets of certain ICs and use recommended parts. This could have been any one of my suggestions above, or possibly something else.

Other time, I have just used a cheap one where things aren't performance critical. Other times I have needed performance so have tested the device with different parts and chose the one that worked best. I don;t think there will be a definitive answer unless the designer happens to come by. But the reasons I suggested are quite common.

Comment: Thanks for illuminating the engineering standpoint of it!

Answer (score 8):

Look into the Bourns SRF1260 datasheet: Multiple applications: parallel, series, dual-inductor and transformer.

Clearly the designer opted for parallel connection, thus doubling the current rating.